# How to mod_rewrite "ONE file" from .php to .html in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

What is the syntax to mod_rewrite "ONE file" from .php to .html in .htaccess?

I have syntax for ALL files, but how do I do that for one file?

Answer (score 0):

In htaccess in the document root :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteRule ^file.php$ /file.html [L]
```

This will internally map /file.php to /file.html

Comment: That didnt work. I put "RewriteRule ^upload.php$ /upload.html [L]" It just give me  :  Multiple Choices

The document name you requested (/upload.html) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.
Available documents:

/upload.php (common basename)